# How to display data from one column to three?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display data, from my database, but it only go like a list. I want them to display like in 3 different columns and next starting again.

Now it's :

1

2

3

4

5

6

And I want it to be :

1  -  2  -  3

4 - 5 - 6

```
     <table>
            <?php
            while ($Tab = $RequestStatement->fetch()) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $Tab["Name"] ?></td>
                    
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>


        </table>
<?php
```

Any idea how to make it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
<?php
 $idx = 0;
 while ($Tab = $RequestStatement->fetch()) {    ?>
<?php if ($idx % 3 == 0) { ?> <tr><?php } ?>
    <td><?php echo $Tab["Name"] ?></td>
   <?php
    $idx++;
    if ($idx % 3 == 0) { ?>
    </tr><?php } ?>
    <?php }
   ?>
```

Comment: Thank you bob for your answer, i did try the code but it's didn't change anything

Comment: please check i updated the code

Comment: Oh i think we miss understood ! I did use number for the example but i want the name from my database to be in place like i show with number ! Sorry

Comment: np, i used for loop just to show info as i don't have access to db but you can replace that with your database fetch

Comment: I m not that confident with php, you say i can replace it with my fetch. But what should i change in your code to make it taking the name in database ?

Comment: edited code again for you